# Why karate feature cannot access a JS object's methods when creating it with 'class'?

Tags: javascript, karate

In `karate-config.js`, when I create a JavaScript object using the 'class' keyword and then add an instance of it to the karate config, a feature cannot access the object's methods (can only access the constructor's properties).

Why is that?

See a possible workaround below but I prefer using the ES6 style.

The following **is not** working:

```js
function fn() {
  
  // define my object using 'class'
  class My {
    constructor(foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
    }
    
    bar() {
      return this.foo;
    }
  }
  
  // instanciate it
  var my = new My("x");
  
  // test accessing the 'bar' method: works
  karate.log(my.bar()); // prints "x"

  // adding instance to karate config
  var config = {
    my: my
  }
  
  return config;
}
```

In a feature, if I access the `my.bar()` method, it fails because it doesn't know a property named 'bar' and if I print the object, it only returns the constructor's properties:

```
Feature: Access the 'bar' method

Scenario: Print it
    * print my
    * print my.bar()
```

Output:

```
13:52:28.530 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] karate-config.js
13:52:29.309 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - x
13:52:29.346 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "foo": "x"
}

13:52:29.359 [main]  ERROR com.intuit.karate - features/my.feature:5
* print my.bar()
js failed:
>>>>
01: karate.log('[print]',my.bar())
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (bar) on {foo=x} failed due to: Unknown identifier: bar
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
...
```

---

**Possible workaround** but I prefer using the ES6 style ('class' keyword) because my object is a bit more complex.

Now, if I'm using the old fashioned (non ES6 style) way without 'class' keyword, then it works:

```js
function fn() {
  // define my object the old fashioned way
  function My(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = () => this.foo;
  }
  
  // instanciate it
  var my = new My("x");
  
  // test accessing the 'bar' method: works
  karate.log(my.bar()); // prints "x"

  // adding instance to karate config
  var config = {
    my: my
  }
  
  return config;
}
```

Output:

```
13:57:57.286 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] karate-config.js
13:57:58.041 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - x
13:57:58.073 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "foo": "x",
  "bar": "com.intuit.karate.graal.JsValue$SharableMembersAndInstantiable@546621c4"
}

13:57:58.078 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] x
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: features/my.feature
scenarios:  1 | passed:  1 | failed:  0 | time: 0,0067
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Karate uses the Graal JS engine which does support some ES6 syntax. The focus has been on just re-use of logic. Personally I believe that you should use as little JS as possible when using Karate.

That said, you are *most* welcome to dive into the code, figure out how we could possibly support what you are asking for and submit a pull request or two.

Comment: Not sure if I can follow: You see that *within* the `karate-config.js` it works like a charm: `karate.log(my.bar());` prints `x` as expected... what means that the Graal JS engine supports it.

But why not within a feature?

Comment: @droptix to put this another way, I really haven't thought about where karate does js evaluation and what the differences are. it needs research.

Comment: @droptix ok here's an idea. see if an `eval` multi-line block works: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#eval - and note that you can do things like `karate.set('varname', value)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried `karate.set()` but has the same implications with a JS native class-like object.

Comment: Also, the multi-line block doesn't address this because I'm creating the class-like object in the config (not within the feature) to use it in all features.

Now I arranged myself going the old fashioned way using constructor functions: `config.foo = new function(foo) { this.foo=foo; this.bar = () => this.foo; }("x")`

I guess this is a limitation of karate's object conversion from JS to Java.

Note: As I've no background as a Java developer and as I'm just using the standalone karate JAR, I disagree using as little JS as possible :-D It allows me to extend my flexibility in the same way

Comment: @droptix yep, that makes sense. I would really like to support this, but just a little too busy. if you can get some java friend to help you dive into the code, please do consider it

Comment: Hi Peter, unfortunately I don't have a java friend who can help me with this... so I tried on my own. I think I can follow the code a bit:

* ScenarioRuntime `getParentConfig()`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/ScenarioRuntime.java#L74
* `getOrEvalAsMap()`https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/ScenarioRuntime.java#L301
* `setVariable()`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/ScenarioEngine.java#L1209

...

Comment: ...

Finally, I'm not sure whether it lies in the [`Variable`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/Variable.java#L71) or [`JsValue`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/graal/JsValue.java#L49) class.

I guess that complex JavaScript objects (instances) need to be exposed to Java as `com.oracle.truffle.api.interop.java.TruffleMap`, as described here: https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/js/JavaInteroperability/#access-to-javascript-objects-from-java

Comment: I guess the problem is that Karate puts JavaScript objects into Java HashMaps and that's where conversion issues happen. All methods of the JavaScript object's prototype get stripped. I found a hacky workaround: I could explicitly re-declare all methods after creating an instance of a native JavaScript class - this preserves all methods by making them available as instance properties (not just prototype properties). But that's not what I would call a solution. I think that's all I can "help".

Comment: @droptix no worries. karate may stay the way it is - as most users don't seem to have the particular needs you have

Comment: Fine for me. Another question: The docs say 
that you can omit the 'eval' keyword, see https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#eval - 
 But I found that this is not always true. Can you check the following feature snippet? - https://pastebin.com/urXF4kNw - Password: m5jFrkhY9A - Line 17: * foo = new - Foo() is not working without 'eval' - If I use * eval foo = new Foo() then it works. - Bug or design?

Comment: @droptix it should be `* def foo = new Foo()` - that said, you are most welcome to contribute to the docs, everything is open source. `eval` works when you want to run a method or accessor *on* a variable, but yes you found an edge case